# Python \n not working as part of the text to be printed, when read from a csv or text file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, tkinter, newline, csvreader

Here is the code explaining my problem:

```
from tkinter import *
import csv

root= Tk()
root.geometry("1080x720")
TextA, TextB = '',''

ListA = [["Unimportant Title"],["This is a sentence","\n I start the first line of the next line","\nHelp me"], ["sublist", "number 2"]]
for element in ListA[1]:
    TextA = TextA + element

ListB = []
with open ('demo.csv', 'r', newline="\n") as t:
    r = csv.reader(t, delimiter='|')
    for lines in r:
        ListB.append(lines)
    t.close
print(ListB)
for element in ListB[1]:
    TextB = TextB + element

label1 = Label(root, font=("Calibri", 14), text=TextA, fg="white", bg="#282828")
label1.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.3)
label2 = Label(root, font=("Calibri", 14), text=TextB, fg="white", bg="#282828")
label2.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.5)

root.mainloop()
```

And this is the contents of `demo.csv`:

```
"Unimportant Title"
"This is a sentence"|"\n I start the first line of the next line"|"\nHelp me"
"sublist"|"number 2"
```

The problem I am facing is that when the label displays `TextA`, the `\n` is recognised as the newline character and I get an output like this, which is exactly what I want:

```
This is a sentence
I start the first line of the next line
Help me
```

But when the label displays `TextB` which is read from the csv file, the `\n` is not recognised and I do not get the output I desired. Instead I get it like this:

```
This is a sentence\n I start the first line of the next line\nHelp me
```

What should I do?

I have tried both removing and keeping the `newline="\n"` but it did not work...

I know this seems really specific but this is a vital part of the code I am working on. So far I haven't been able to find a solution or rather where to apply that solution.

Comment: You'll need to transform the *literal text value* of `\n` (two characters, \ followed by n) into the newline character *after* it is read in from the file. The `newline` option does not apply as that is the *literal text* in the file as *part of* a single CSV line.

Comment: On the other hand, in `"foo\nbar"` the \n is an *escape sequence* in a *string literal* that is converted to the newline character by Python *as it parses* the source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the output of `print(ListB)`:

```
[['Unimportant Title'], ['This is a sentence', '\\n I start the first line of the next line', '\\nHelp me'], ['sublist', 'number 2']]
```

You will find that `\n` in the file is read as `\\n`.  You need to convert it back to `\n`:

```py
for element in ListB[1]:
    TextB += element.replace('\\n', '\n')
```

Comment: It works now! Thanks a lot!